# C# - using namespace across files within a shared namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a namespace that will change somewhat frequently in my project (each product generation) and would like to keep references to that specific namespace contained to the file where I define a base class.  In other files I define child classes that usually can get by with getting references to the namespace by inheritance, but I am having trouble with one case as the objects are very specific and I would prefer to link to the namespace within the base class rather than each object.

```
BaseClass.cs

namespace CommonNameSpace
{
   using _productSpecificNameSpace;

   _productSpecificNameSpace.thing.otherthing thingotherthingGood = _productSpecificNameSpace.thing.otherthing.Success;
   _productSpecificNameSpace.thing.otherthing thingotherthingBad = _productSpecificNameSpace.thing.otherthing.SpecificFailure;

   public class BaseClass
   {
   }
}


SubClass.cs

namespace CommonNameSpace
{
   public class SubClass : BaseClass
   {
       var yeaOrNeigh = thingotherthingGood
   }
}
```

How can I access _productSpecificNameSpace in SubClass.cs without having to call it _productSpecificNameSpace in each subclass, or name every possible object that I will need in BaseClass?  Is there a way to get an alias to a namespace attached to a class for inheriting?

Edit: Ideally, I would like to have access to the data types in the interchangeable namespace, as it is mostly a library of enums.  Wouldn't having an interface replace the type of these enums with an interface type that would be incomparable with calls to APIs expecting the underlying type?

Comment: Why not jsut use a abstract baseclass in all your code, only swapping out the specific class you instantiate into the variables? Swapping out implementations is literay waht Abstract Class and Interfaces were invented for.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an interface, you can then instantiate the generation you want to at runtime, without affecting any existing code:

```
interface IMyThing
{
    void DoStuff()
}

abstract class BaseThing : IMyThing
{
   public virtual void DoStuff()
}
```

Generation1:

```
class MyGen1 : BaseThing
{
   public override void DoStuff()
   {
      // I'm Gen 1
   }
}
```

Generation2:

```
class MyGen2 : BaseThing
{
  public override void DoStuff()
  {
     // I'm Gen 2
  }
}
```